# Jupyter notebook - connect to the same kernel session from a command line ipython?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

Suppose I've a Jupyter notebook loaded in a browser. Is that possible to somehow run a command line ipython session which connect to the same kernel instance as the one used by the notebook (i.e they can see the same set of variables)? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes! After starting/loading an IPython notebook, open up a terminal and connect a command line ipython session using the `--existing` parameter:

```
jupyter console --existing
```

By default, it will connect to the latest started IPython kernel. To select a different kernel to connect to, look in the log of the Jupyter notebook for lines like these:

```
[I 09:47:54.462 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 06c9ffae-ae9f-4c22-93c0-4eacf23672b1
```

To connect to this kernel, do:

```
jupyter console --existing 06c9ffae-ae9f-4c22-93c0-4eacf23672b1
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify your own Python REPL, like [ptpython](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/ptpython). I tried the `--kernel` option, but that doesn't work (at least the way I'm using it -- which is to specify the path to my `ptpython` installation).

Comment: The system works by having one headless python server, to which multiple clients can connect. So you'd need to have ptpython connect to the ipython kernel, but it doesn't seem to support it: https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/ptpython/issues/37

Comment: There are some quirks in doing that: although I like to use this solution, I haven't found a way to: 1. cancel a command from the console (with Ctrl-C), because it will say: "ERROR: Cannot interrupt kernels we didn't start"; 2. quit the console (Ctrl-D) without interrupting the kernel... (Yes it seems paradoxical)

Answer (score 1):

With [JupyterLab](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) it's possible to open a linked console by right clicking on any Notebook and selecting **New Console for Notebook** (as mentioned in @machine_building's comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54370829/436794)). That will show a connected console beside/below the Notebook, which one can interact with like in a terminal with command history etc.