# Is it possible to show a console in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I would like to be able to fiddle around in the environment using a console in a Jupyter notebook. Adding an additional cell means that I always have to scroll to the very bottom or create new cells wherever I want a 'console-like' text field. Is it possible to have a permanent console window, e.g. at the bottom of the window?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can get get this with jupyterlab. But I cannot tell how stable it is right now.

Answer (score 15):

You can fire up a Jupyter qt console that is connected to the same IPython kernel 
http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Connecting%20with%20the%20Qt%20Console.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I assume the qt console will not run in the browser, right? I'm running my jupyter notebook on a remote machine and access them via the browser, so a GUI window is not possible for me.

Comment: I wouldn't rule it out. Since everything is client/server I believe that the notebook and the qt console are just different front-ends to the same backend, and I can't think of any reason that they cant both work with a remote machine. However, I've never tried and can't dig into that further at the moment

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your question correctly. You are correct that it will not run in the browser. However, if you are on a client with a browser, can that client also run a qt console that will connect to the Jupyter server? Maybe it's not possible but worth checking into

Comment: After some research, it seems qtconsole is just for python kernel. Is there any way to have console for other kernels in general? I'm a converter from Rstudio, and currently running irkernel under Jupyter

Comment: https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel clearly states an example using the qtconsole with irkernel.  I have never tried it, # “ir” is the kernel name installed by the above `IRkernel::installspec()`
# change if you used a different name!
jupyter qtconsole --kernel=ir
jupyter console --kernel=ir

Answer (score 15):

From the [documentation](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Connecting%20with%20the%20Qt%20Console.html) there are two alternatives and steps are the followings:

## First alternative

1. In your `jupyter notebook` run the following magic command in a cell:

   %qtconsole

It will start a new ipython qtconsole.

## Second alternative

1. In your `jupyter notebook` run the following magic command in a cell:

   %connect_info

The output will be something like this:

```
{
  "stdin_port": 234, 
  "ip": "127.0.0.1", 
  "control_port": 324234 , 
  "hb_port": 50698, 
  "signature_scheme": "hasgd6", 
  "key": "8d91ba69-fasdfasdgadga6e34", 
  "kernel_name": "", 
  "shell_port": 6****9, 
  "transport": "tcp", 
  "iopub_port": 3***0
}

Paste the above JSON into a file, and connect with:
    $> jupyter <app> --existing <file>
or, if you are local, you can connect with just:
    $> jupyter <app> --existing kernel-773f517f-bf26-4102-9329-888a2dac0f4e.json
or even just:
    $> jupyter <app> --existing
if this is the most recent Jupyter kernel you have started.
```

2. Write in your terminal the solution that fits your needs. For example, I'm using it locally and I want a qtconsole:

   jupyter qtconsole --existing kernel-773f517f-bf26-4102-9329-888a2dac0f4e.json

This will open a `qtconsole` using the same kernel, so you will have access to all the variables.

Comment: Don't know why alternative 1 not work, run %qtconsole but nothing happens, while the second one works

Answer (score 11):

You can use JupyterLab.

This brings notebook, console, terminal together in a single interface just like R-Studio.
[JupyterLab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juQLs.png)

Comment: Agree Jupyter Lab looks really promising for this. If you do `File -> New -> Notebook` and then do `File -> New -> Console` then it asks you to choose a kernel. At the bottom of the list you see "Use Kernel from Other Session" from the notebook and you can connect to that. Then you can rearrange your tabs as you like for the best workflow.

Comment: Yes, with JupyterLab you can simply right-click on your active notebook, and then click "New Console for Notebook" to open up a console that's hooked up to the same Python kernel! With this, you can play around with all the dataframes and objects without messing up the notebook outputs.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know about a terminal in a cell, but you can open a new tab that has (only) a terminal in it. There is an option in the upper right menu of the file browser:

[image]

You have to install the package `terminado`, and it only works on unix.

Comment: This should be the answer. It works for me in macOS. @Danderssen I think you should accept this one.

Comment: This will not allow you to access the notebook environment.

Comment: Works in Windows too.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me though. Type the below commands in this order.

1. %qtconsole
2. %connect_info
3. Restart the Kernel and clear all outputs.

These steps worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned, I use JupyterLab for this.  I wanted to expand on this a bit though since there were still some elements unclear to me at first:

1. To get the console to open, select notebook tab to make active, then File > New Console for Notebook.
2. To actually run commands in the console, Shift+Enter works.  Regular Ctrl+Enter will not work, and Enter will just newline.  This can be verified if Debug mode is active, as variables in the current workspace will change/ update.

Unfortunately, the console code will not run if stopped on a breakpoint in another cell, meaning this technique cannot be used to probe code contained within a loop, like can be done in RStudio and other similar IDE's.