# connect to same IPython kernel from different notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

I know it is possible to connect to a running kernel from a terminal: [Juypter notebook - connect to the same kernel session from a command line ipython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43083966/juypter-notebook-connect-to-the-same-kernel-session-from-a-command-line-ipytho), but, is it possible to connect to the same kernel from another notebook?

Answer (score 2):

If you use Jupyterlab it is possible to attach a notebook to a kernel started by another notebook.

[image]

Comment: thank you, it's good to know, but I'd like to do it in a Jupyter notebook if possible